# Reading characters from a txt file, encoding, and writing into a binary file

Tags: c, unix, binary, bitwise-operators

I'm writing a program to read 4 characters at a time from a text file, pack them into an integer, 'encrypt' the integer by shifting it 3 units to the right in a circle, and write the encrypted integer into a binary file.

Original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "encoding.h"

#define KEY 3

int encrypt(int a); 
int pack(char a, char b, char d, char c);

void encoding(char itxt[], char obin[]){ 

        char four[4];

        FILE *inp=fopen(itxt,"r");
        if(!inp){printf("Unable to open %c", inp); return 1;} 

        FILE *outp=fopen(obin,"wb");
        if(!outp){printf("Unable to open %c\n", obin); return 1;} 

        while(fgets(four, 4, inp) != NULL){ 

                int a;

                a = pack(four[0], four[1], four[2], four[3]);
                a = encrypt(a);

                fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, outp);
        }

        printf("Encoding complete!\n");

        fclose(inp);
        fclose(outp);
}

int pack(char a, char  b, char c, char d){ 

        int p = a;

        p = (p<<CHAR_BIT) | b;
        p = (p<<CHAR_BIT) | c;
        p = (p<<CHAR_BIT) | d;

        return p;
}

int encrypt(int a){

        int obin = a>>KEY;

        return obin;
}
```

The code compiles but does not write anything into the binary file. Any feedback, hints, or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

*Edit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "encoding.h"

#define KEY 3

unsigned int encrypt(int a); 
unsigned int pack(char a, char b, char d, char c);

void encoding(char itxt[], char obin[]){ 

        char four[4];

        FILE *inp=fopen(itxt,"r");
        if(!inp){printf("Unable to open %c", inp); return 1;} 

        FILE *outp=fopen(obin,"wb");
        if(!outp){printf("Unable to open %c\n", obin); return 1;} 

        while(fread(&four, sizeof(char), 4, inp) != NULL){ 

                unsigned int a;

                a = pack(four[0], four[1], four[2], four[3]);
                a = encrypt(a);

                fwrite(&a, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, outp);
        }

        printf("Encoding complete!\n");

        fclose(inp);
        fclose(outp);
}

unsigned int pack(char a, char  b, char c, char d){ 

        int p = a;

        p = (p<<CHAR_BIT) | b;
        p = (p<<CHAR_BIT) | c;
        p = (p<<CHAR_BIT) | d;

        return p;
}

 unsigned int encrypt(int a){

        int obin = (a>>KEY) | (a<<(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a)-KEY)); 

        return obin;
}
```

Comment: is *encoding()* called at all? We don't see this part of the code

Comment: _encoding()_ is called in a separate file, _main.c_. I did not include it but it simply displays the original text file, calls _encoding()_, _decoding()_, and displays the resulting text file.

Comment: For starters, the return type of `pack` is `char`.  That's never going to give you the result you're looking for.  Furthermore, the `>>` operator is not circular.  The high-order bits will be padded with zeros...  well, _might_...  It's really undefined behavior because you're shifting a signed datatype.

Comment: If `encoding` is indeed called and you don't see any error (and input file contains something), even if the encryption / packing is wrong, you should see a result in the written file.

Comment: When you return `p` as a `char` from `pack()`, you throw away the 3 most significant bytes of data.  Change the return type to `unsigned int`.  You have similar mangling problems in `encode()` — and the added complication that the code does not do what you say it should do.  It should take an `unsigned int` too, and return one, and the intermediate result should be `unsigned int` too.  And the possibly signed `char` type used as arguments to `pack()` will cause trouble if plain `char` is signed and you get bytes in the range 0x80..0xFF.  Use explicit `unsigned char`.

Comment: I've changed everything that was mentioned so far but the problem still persists. _encoding()_ is indeed called as it prints "Encoding complete!" but there is no output in the written file.

Comment: You should also be using `fread()` since `fgets(four, 4, inp)` might return 1 to 3 characters plus a null byte.  It will return fewer than 3 characters if a newline happens to be in the way.  It will never return 4 non-null characters.

Comment: Or you could use `getc()` instead of `fread()` to read 4 characters.

Comment: Thank you for the solid advice. I tried to incorporate everything you mentioned into the code (edited above) but continue to come up short.

Comment: I know your new, so I won't ding you, but never **replace** the original question with an edited version. Instead. just add the edited code below the original. That way all the comments still make sense. When you remove the original code, all comments or previous answers addressing issues in the original are rendered meaningless.

Comment: I realize how dumb that was so I've actually edited my question again to include the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edited code is pretty close to operational.  Here's a mildly modified version that seems to work.  The difficulty is that there isn't a decode function to check that encryption is decryptable.

#### Encoding code `enc37.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define KEY 3

unsigned int encrypt(unsigned int a);
unsigned int pack(unsigned char a, unsigned char b, unsigned char d, unsigned char c);
void encoding(const char itxt[], const char obin[]);

void encoding(const char itxt[], const char obin[])
{
    char four[4];

    FILE *inp = fopen(itxt, "r");
    if (!inp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s\n", itxt);
        return;
    }

    FILE *outp = fopen(obin, "wb");
    if (!outp)
    {
        fclose(inp);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s\n", obin);
        return;
    }

    while (fread(&four, sizeof(char), 4, inp) == 4)
    {
        unsigned int a;

        a = pack(four[0], four[1], four[2], four[3]);
        a = encrypt(a);

        fwrite(&a, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, outp);
    }

    printf("Encoding complete!\n");

    fclose(inp);
    fclose(outp);
}

unsigned int pack(unsigned char a, unsigned char b, unsigned char c, unsigned char d)
{
    unsigned int p = a;

    p = (p << CHAR_BIT) | b;
    p = (p << CHAR_BIT) | c;
    p = (p << CHAR_BIT) | d;

    return p;
}

unsigned int encrypt(unsigned int a)
{
    unsigned int obin = (a >> KEY) | (a << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(a) - KEY));

    return obin;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *i_file = "/dev/stdin";
    char *o_file = "/dev/stdout";

    if (argc == 3)
    {
        i_file = argv[1];
        o_file = argv[2];
    }

    encoding(i_file, o_file);
    return 0;
}
```

The argument list handling allows you to specify the file names for input and output on the command line, but it defaults to reading from standard input and writing to standard output.

#### Decoding code `dec37.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define KEY 3

typedef unsigned char Byte;
typedef unsigned int  Uint;

Uint decrypt(Uint a);
Uint pack(Byte a, Byte b, Byte d, Byte c);
void unpack(Uint value, Byte *data);
void decoding(const char ibin[], const char otxt[]);

void decoding(const char ibin[], const char otxt[])
{
    FILE *inp = fopen(ibin, "rb");
    if (!inp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s\n", ibin);
        return;
    }

    FILE *outp = fopen(otxt, "w");
    if (!outp)
    {
        fclose(inp);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s\n", otxt);
        return;
    }

    Uint value;
    while (fread(&value, sizeof(value), 1, inp) == 1)
    {
        Byte four[4];
        value = decrypt(value);
        unpack(value, four);
        fwrite(four, sizeof(four), 1, outp);
    }

    printf("Decoding complete!\n");

    fclose(inp);
    fclose(outp);
}

void unpack(Uint value, Byte *data)
{
    data[0] = (value >> (3 * CHAR_BIT)) & 0xFF;
    data[1] = (value >> (2 * CHAR_BIT)) & 0xFF;
    data[2] = (value >> (1 * CHAR_BIT)) & 0xFF;
    data[3] = (value >> (0 * CHAR_BIT)) & 0xFF;
}

Uint decrypt(Uint a)
{
    Uint obin = (a << KEY) | (a >> (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(a) - KEY));

    return obin;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *i_file = "/dev/stdin";
    char *o_file = "/dev/stdout";

    if (argc == 3)
    {
        i_file = argv[1];
        o_file = argv[2];
    }

    decoding(i_file, o_file);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Testing

If the encrypting program is `enc37` and the decrypting program is `dec37`, then you can run commands like:

```
$ ./enc37 enc37.txt enc37.bin
$ ./dec37 enc37.bin dec37.txt
$ diff enc37.txt dec37.txt
$
```

as long as the input file (`enc37.txt`) is a multiple of 4 bytes long.  I used `enc37.c` and `dec37.c` as input files at various times.

You can also use the decryption and encryption programs in the reverse order, and still get round-trip conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be shifting a potentially signed, negative integer to the right; all such `char`s should be translated to `unsigned long`, not *`int`*; not only can `int` store *negative* numbers (which I'm sure you don't want, but this will also cause subtly different behaviour based on underlying integer representation). There's truncation, too; `int` can't portably store four 8-bit octets, where-as `unsigned long` can.

`CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a)-KEY` seems like it could violate padding in addition to the signage issue, not that you're likely to run into these issues. Nonetheless, they should be fixed to avoid wasting time debugging issues that seem obscure and could be difficult to patch.

You can split an `unsigned long` into the two components you desire (let's call them `head` and `tail`) providing you derive those masks for `head` and `tail` from `ULONG_MAX`.

```
unsigned long head_mask = ULONG_MAX >> key,
              tail_mask = ~head_mask;
```

... or

```
unsigned long head_mask = ULONG_MAX << key,
              tail_mask = ~head_mask;
```

... etc. These will produce bitwise-opposing masks which you can then use the `&` operation (as you are) to extract your two groups of characters. `head_mask` will need to be shifted right by `key` to bring it in line, but at least this'll guarantee you something well defined.